# Scala - Check if a class is imported or not

Tags: scala

In Scala console the command:

```
import testPackage._
```

will give the below output:

```
scala> import testPackage._
import testPackage._
```

But after importing how to check what are the classes imported in the console or how to list the classes (of testPackage) in the console (just for verification). Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the REPL I'm not sure if there's a command for listing all imported classes, however what you can do is use the tabbed completion, just type in:

```
scala> val tmp : testPackage.
```

and then hit TAB.  You should get a list of the types available within that scope.

HTH

Comment: Hi Jonny, am using the Scala Console integrated with eclipse, I followed the method you posted but when I hit TAB, the cursor just moves, and it's not showing the list actually. what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: I don't use the Eclipse Scala IDE...but that sounds like the console there isn't a full REPL.   What you might try doing is launch just a standard Terminal/command shell within the IDE (think you can do that within Eclipse?) and then just run the full Scala REPL from within there...I generally have an IDE open in one window (or one half of the window or whatever) and then a shell window open in another...I find the that terminals within IDE's (Eclipse in particular) can be a bit flakey - they're not full terminals generally.

Comment: Ok Jonny Thank you :)